# How do I filter the current year?

Tags: 7, views, tokens

Initially, I have installed the [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module and created a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) block containing years.

I want to filter out the current year from the block (it should not show the current year).

In filter criteria, I have changed content:year ([current-date:custom:Y]), but it is not filtering the current year, and it is showing as follows:

- 2013(3)
- 2014(5)
- 2015(6)
- 2016(2)

I am expecting the output to be as follows:

- 2013(3)
- 2014(5)
- 2015(6)

How can I achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if using the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module could be a solution. Here are some quotes about it (from its project page):

> ... allows to format date fields using SQL.
>
> The core functionality is to remove the date formatting from render() and put it in query(). I.e. format date values using SQL's DATE_FORMAT rather than PHP's format_date.
>   This is achieved by assigning a new default handler to node 'created' and 'changed' date fields. This handler extends and overrides views's build in views_handler_field_date.
>
> The UI is completely unobtrusive, only a single checkbox "Use SQL to format dates" is added to the handler configuration popup.

Your question is not about creating charts in Drupal, but you may want to refer to [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) also for an example of how we typically use it within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.